# Can you use the developer console logged in as another user?

Tags: force.com, developer-console

Can you use the developer console while logged in as another user to debug something? I can launch the console, but it just seems to hang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that we can't use the developer console if user which you logged in has no rights for using it. I'm getting popup with an error during such loading the developer console and after that the console just hangs.

I guess that one possible way for getting the log of this user is setting up this user as a monitored user and analyze plain text logs.

**UPDATE**

I've found the following solution:

You can login as any user which has no right for using the developer console.
You need to set a log monitoring for this user

[image]

After that you can open anonymous browser window and login as SysAdmin/Developer to this org and open developer console. After that you have to uncheck [Show My Current Logs Only] checkbox

[image]

Now you can see logs of selected user.

Comment: I tried the debug log, and I couldn't get what I needed. that's why I was looking into the console.

Comment: @nivyaj I understand that the developer console is much better than plain logs. But what are you looking for in developer console which can't be found in a plain text log?

Comment: FWIW, if the user doesn't have access to the console, while it appears "hung", you'll see error messages on your browser's JavaScript console (F12, usually). These errors just don't show up in the UI, and so it appears frozen.

Comment: @nivyaj please see update

Answer (score 1):

yes we can use the Dev console even after logged in as other user but the user should have access to the Dev console.